# postgres updated trigger function but no effect

Tags: postgresql, triggers, procedure

I have a Postgres 9.4 database with a trigger on insert on a table with partitions (child tables). The trigger calls a procedure that needs to be updated regularly for new partition tables. I found that after updating the trigger procedure, the trigger still seems to call the previous version of that procedure, as it throws an exception if the insert is out of range in regards to available partitions.
How can I force Postgres to use the correct trigger procedure?

Kind regards,
Kai

Comment: How do you try to select the correct one? Without code, it's hard to help you.

Comment: i did a `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` with the trigger procedure name that is called in the `BEFORE INSERT ON ` trigger on the parent table. the content of the function checks the record creation date and sorts it into one of the partitions. A new partition was added with the next date range but the trigger call complains still for out of range even if the trigger procedure shows to be as expected on a `\df+` call

Comment: Once you replace a function will immediately start using it. Are you sure you that you (1) commited the transaction where you changed the trigger, (2) are looking in the correct database and schema and (3) aren't looking at different functions (even with similar names)?

Comment: And did you create the trigger using the correct function? Without code, we can't see what might go wrong, we can only guess.

Comment: [edit] your question and add the code for the trigger function and your complete `create trigger` statement

Answer (score 0):

The question is invalid. the problem was not of a procedure not called/updated, just a stupid timezone issue.